# Scaling image in Parallax.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallax, parallax.js

I apologize in advance for my English, I'm using Parallax.js on my page and I ran into the following problem. The picture that I use to create the parallax has a resolution of 3160x2840 but my screen is 1920x1080. Is it possible to make this photo scale to the screen resolution?

Answer (score 0):

***here is a trick, specify class="parallax-image" to your img tag***

```
.parallax-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

other way you can use

```
width: 100vw
```

Comment: it doesn't change anything, it looks like it's being ignored

Comment: you can use
width: 100vw
height: 100vw

but it is not recommended